# Stop Angular UI bootstrap dropdown from closing in certain cases?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, event-bubbling

I have a dropdown which contains tabs and buttons. I want to be able to click the tabs without the dropdown closing but if I click a button it will close.

I used $event.stopPropagation() to stop the closing but obviously this blocks the buttons closing it too.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why not keep the `stopPropagation()` and close the dropdown yourself in the buttons' `ng-click` handlers? (And set the `auto-close` option on the dropdown to `outsideClick` or `disabled`)

Comment: I had the stopPropagation() on the tabset, this block everything. outsideClick seem to work in a plunker I make but not in my app, odd.

Comment: I was working off angular ui bootstrap 0.13.0, moving to 0.13.1 made it work again. I was a known bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the dropdown will automatically close if any of its elements is clicked, you can change this behavior by setting the auto-close option as follows:

`always` - (Default) automatically closes the dropdown when any of its elements is clicked.

`outsideClick` - closes the dropdown automatically only when the user clicks any element outside the dropdown.

`disabled` - disables the auto close. You can then control the open/close status of the dropdown manually, by using `is-open`. Please notice that the dropdown will still close if the toggle is clicked, the esc key is pressed or another dropdown is open.

Here is a sample : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jvR1WcMq2eyawSIoVSbc?p=preview)

```
    <div class="btn-group" dropdown auto-close="disabled">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Action</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Any ideas how to do this with angular-bootstrap v0.12.1? I copied your code directly in and it does not appear to work. Thanks.

Comment: Can we disable the auto-close on some specific li element?

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing, to autoClose outside click but in vanilla js? I am been trying e.stopPropagation and it isn't working.